# .NET 2.0 compatibility issue with Chrome and IE 10

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0

We've a .NET 2.0 website that uses Javascript to do a lot of things, such as populating drop down lists and validating pages.

users have reported some problems when they use the website with Chrome, Firefox or IE 10 or later. The problem or problems i should say are different

- some drop down list don't get populated, just empty lists.
- Labels are not shown, so you see a text box with no labels!

anyone had same issue before?

Thanks

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Maybe Developer Tools(F12) JS Debug output would be enough too. Anyway the provided information is not enough obviously.